# how do i make a badge notify disappear across all web pages after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

Please how do i make a badge notify icon hide after the user clicks on it and stay hidden across all pages when i navigate. here's my code

```
<h:outputLink value="" id="but" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()" style="border-bottom:none">x</h:outputLink>
        <h:outputLink value="home.xhtml" id="ab" onclick="closeNav()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style=" color: blue;"></span><span id="ab1">Home</span></h:outputLink>     
        <h:outputLink value="profile.xhtml" id="ser" onclick="closeNav()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user custom"></span><span id="ser1">Profile</span></h:outputLink>
        <h:outputLink value="transaction.xhtml" id="cl" onclick="closeNav()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></span><span class="badge badge-notify">!</span><span id="cl1">Transaction</span></h:outputLink>
```

here's my css:

```
.badge-notify
    {
        background:red;
        position:absolute;

  }
```

here's my javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function()
{
  $(".badge-notify").click(function()
   {
       $(".badge-notify").fadeOut("slow");
   });
});
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The reason it keeps showing up on every page is because you aren't keeping track of whether it's been clicked before or not.

One solution is to set the display of the badge to none by default, like so:

```
.badge-notify {
    display: none;
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
}
```

and to have a variable saved in their localStorage to see if they've clicked the badge before or not. So if we do something like:

```
localStorage.setItem("seen_badge", "false");
```

then we've created a variable that will now work across all pages of your site. So, using some jQuery we check if the user has seen the badge before, and if not, we make it visible:

```
if(localStorage.seen_badge === "false") {
    $('.badge-notify').show();
}
```

Next, if the user clicks on the badge to close/dismiss it, we change the value of seen_badge to true, and that way it won't show up again like so:

```
$('.badge-notify').on('click', function() {
    $(this).hide();
    localStorage.seen_badge = "true";
});
```